# EmEditor でマクロをインクルードすると、「文字が正しくありません」というエラーが出ます

Tags: emeditor

普通にマクロをひとつにしてそのまま貼り付けただけであれば、普通どおりに動きます。

```c
#include "インクルードするマクロ.jsee"
```

このまえに、単純な複数のマクロをインクルードで動作するかを実験したときは動作しました。
文字が正しくありませんとは何のことでしょうか？

EmEditorのヘルプを見ましたが検索ではヒットしませんでした。この原因は何がありますでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 正確性のため「文字が正しくありません」というメッセージを含む画面図を載せてください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。1枚しか載せられないようですので合成しました。このマクロの中身をそのまま同じ所に貼り付けたら動きました。インクルードにするとこのようになります。マクロの記述そのものは動作しているようですが、何が正しくないのかわからない状況です。マクロファイルを他に変えても同様になります。

Answer (score 1):

`#include` は、`//` で始まるコメント行を除き、スクリプトのメイン コードの上の最初の行に指定する必要があります。この画面図の例の 77 行目のように、空の行を含めることはできません。

参考： [#include 指示子](http://www.emeditor.org/ja/macro_directive_include.html)

Comment: 速い回答ありがとうございます。御厚意､感謝しております。インクルードのマクロを上のコードに空行を開けずにくっつけて配置しましたが、同様でした。上下に空行があるといけないのかと思いまして、すべての行をコメントかコードか空行が上下無いように先頭にコメントマークを付けた状態にしましたが同様でした。空行があるのとなぜだめなんでしょうか？途中の部分で「ここに○○のマクロを挿入したい」とかです。もしくはインクルードの場合は、マクロのコードを書いたものとインクルードをあわせて使うハイブリッド型の制作ではなく、連携させるすべてのマクロを100％すべてインクルードだけのものでないと動かないのでしょうか？だとすると、なぜハイブリッド制作はだめなんでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 何々の処理のコード→
何々の処理のコード→
#include "何々の処理.jsee"→このように適材適所にインクルードで埋め込むということはできない仕様なのでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: その通りです。マクロは JavaScript、VBScript だけでなく、様々な未知のスクリプトにも対応しています。そのため、どのような言語にでも対応できるよう、#include はファイルの先頭のみで利用できるようになっています。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。インクルードは、すべてインクルードファイルを並べて動作させるということにします。教えていただき、ありがとうございます。

Comment: お世話になっております。この質問の続きなのですが、単独では完全にサクサク動くマクロが#include ""のリンクにすると、EmEditorマクロエラー「文字が正しくありません。」と出てインクルードしたマクロの画面の行数を指定してきます。単独では何も指摘しないのにです。今回は、インクルードのファイルはコードの合間に混じった物ではなく、単独で行も全部詰めています。なぜ単独では動作するマクロがインクルードで並べると文字が正しくないと言うことになるのでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。